# Android Multithreading - WaitForGcToComplete after sending app to background

Tags: android, multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm using Android L for some heavily multi-threaded operations, using multiple ThreadPoolExecutors to run queues of AsyncTasks.

When my app goes to the background, I start seeing numerous logs for...

`I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for ##.#####ms for cause XXXXX`

...with an occasional...

`I/art: No such thread id for suspend: ###`.

It seems clear that something is going on that's making GC take longer than expected.  The log gets generated by art/runtime/gc/heap.cc deep in the AOSP.  The secondary log message indicates it's probably related to my thread pools.  What isn't clear is why this is only happening (i.e. getting logged) when the app is sent to the background.

I haven't seen any crashes yet due to this, but I have a lot more testing to go through.  Has anyone out there run into issues coinciding with these logs?

Comment: Same problem, would be happy to see an answer.

Comment: A month later and still no errors specific to these logs.  I refactored my code to reuse ThreadPoolExecutors - among other changes - and the No such thread id for suspend logs seem to be far less prevalent.

Comment: My app seems to crash sometimes, not sure if it's because of this but I have this error in my logs a lot.

Comment: Can you check if it is somehow connected with destruction of your activity? Once it is in background, it is more probable that an activity will be destroyed. I don't know how you deal with your pool on activity's life-cycle methods, but maybe you've introduced some bugs there ...

Comment: I have seen this problem when you try to serialize an object to json using gson when the app is try to close or pause an Activity or Service. The new Android VM seems to be doing something funny with GSON and somehow setting up a race condition where GSON keeps trying to finish its work, but the VM keeps trying to kill it.